# How to declare a variable based on value of another Integer?

Tags: python

On my recent project I am facing with new obstruction where I need to declare a variable based on value of another string.

What I need:

```
'Hai'= 2
```

The String `Hai` is initialized at variable `x`,

`x='hai'` then I need `'hai'= 2`

Now all I want is the value of `x` to point to a `int` (different `int` for different values of `x`).

So if,

```
x='bye'
```

then,

```
'bye'=20
```

Comment: I think you are looking for dictionaries. You can use a dictionary to store key value pairs such as `'bye' = 20`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get a dictionary as @Saadat said:

```
x = {'hai': 2, 'bye': 20}
```

Now

```
x['hai']
```

Will give 2 and the other key will give 20
Or:

```
y='hai'
z = x[y] #z=2
```

Also another worse approach:

```
if x == 'hai':
  hai = 2
elif x == 'bye'
  bye = 20

...
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you are describing a dictionary:

A dictionary provides a mapping between two different values (also known as an associative array in other languages). You can declare one in Python like this:

```
mydict = {"hai": 2, "bye": 20}

print(mydict["hai"])
# 2

print(mydict["bye"])
# 20
```

You can then use variables as the key to access the dictionary:

```py
mykey = "bye"

print(mydict[mykey])
# 20
```

For more details, please see the [Python docs for dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't go with dictionary and need to declare a variable name & value at runtime. We can achieve this with `setattr()`

Try this,

```
class Sample:
   pass

obj = Sample()
x = 'hai'
setattr(obj, x, 20)
print(obj.hai)
```